# tensorflow nightly wheel in python

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-wheel

I'm newbie in python.
Someone can help me with the diference between 
tf-nightly and tensorflow  wheels?

What I should install?

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tensorflow  vs 
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tf-nightly

I'm stuck with nightly packages. I don't know what is that.

Comment: Better not install nightly unless you want development code and you know what you're doing. Install `pip3 install -U tensorflow`.

Comment: Thanks. brief and concise.

Answer (score 5):

I have searched the [softwareengineering.stackexchange.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/56490/203948) and found this:

> No, it means that every night, everything that has been checked into source control is built. That build is a "nightly build".

And in the installation page TF says that:

> People who are a little more adventurous can also try our nightly binaries

So, we can conjecture that the tf-nightly is only for those who are adventurous, because it may have built the untested or not sufficiently tested source code into the binary form, which may result in unexpected errors or failures.

And if you employ the "conservative" installation, `pip3 install -U tensorflow` the binary was built from the fully tested source code(especially by(or exposed to the eyes of) users like us), usually tagged with `1.x` in the github branch.

I highly recommend you install from source code yourself, you can better tailor it and get better performance. Just follow this [official tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources). You may need to download some pdg files from elsewhere you can because nvidia is under maintenance as it stated on the related pages.

Answer (score 0):

By default, you should use `tensorflow`, not the nightly variants. Yet, some problems that persist in the official tensorflow packages can be fixed in nightly. See [ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense is incompatible with the layer: its rank is undefined, but the layer requires a defined rank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55682557/valueerror-input-0-of-layer-dense-is-incompatible-with-the-layer-its-rank-is-u).