# ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense is incompatible with the layer: its rank is undefined, but the layer requires a defined rank

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tensorflow-hub

When trying the example at https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/hub_with_keras at a local computer with tf `'2.0.0-alpha0'` (download, `pip`-download `hub '0.4.0-dev'` and remove `!pip...` lines, install tf 2, remove `enable_v2_behavior`
, run [file](https://gist.github.com/serv-inc/eace7d57a2086750800f6d4a5bc6ada3)), it failed with

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense is incompatible with the layer: its rank is undefined, but the layer requires a defined rank.

It runs fine on Google colab though. Why is this and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Does it help to replace `tensorflow=2.0.0-alpha0` with `tf-nightly-2.0-preview`?

Comment: @arnoegw: YES! thanks so much

Comment: @arnoegw: feel welcome to post an answer (to save time, you can simply copy-paste the "this is fixed..." part of mine ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As proposed by @arnoegw in the comments, this is fixed in `tf-nightly-2.0-preview`. So until it lands in production, just use

```
pip install tf-nightly-2.0-preview
```